# Semantic conflict of [nan]: NaN (not-a-number) and Nan (native abstractions for Node.js)

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

Try searching [nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nan) with [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) or [v8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/v8) on *Stack Overflow*.
We can find quite a lot of questions with [nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nan) misused.

Although currently the tag [nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nan) means `NaN` (not-a-number), they used `nan` to mean [*Nan* (native abstractions for Node.js)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nan).

How could we resolve this problem?

Comment: This looks straightforward: retag the mistagged questions to [tag:node.js-nan]. (It would also make sense to retag, or perhaps synonimise, [tag:node-nan] and [tag:nodejs-nan].)